# How can I do handwriting recognition each time a user has finished tracing a stroke?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, inkcanvas, handwriting-recognition

Basing myself on the code given by MSDN for [Handwriting Recognition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt617337.aspx) in windows 10 apps, I tried to have it recognize the handwriting automatically after the user has finished tracing an ink stroke rather than when clicking a button.

I have been able to do something similar in a Windows 8.1 metro app by calling my handwriting recognition method when the PointerReleased event was triggered in my canvas. It worked great and I tried to emulate the same behavior in UWP.

The PointerReleased event was not firing in the UWP app so I used the InkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeInput.StrokeEnded event instead to call this method :

```
async void RecognizeAsync(InkStrokeInput input, PointerEventArgs e)
{
    IReadOnlyList<InkStroke> currentStrokes =myInkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();
    if (currentStrokes.Count > 0)
    {
        var recognitionResults = await inkRecognizerContainer.RecognizeAsync(myInkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer, InkRecognitionTarget.All);

        if (recognitionResults.Count > 0)
        {
            // Display recognition result
            string str = "Recognition result:";
            foreach (var r in recognitionResults)
            {
                str += " " + r.GetTextCandidates()[0];
            }
            Status.Text=str;
        }
        else
        {
            Status.Text = "No text recognized.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Status.Text="Must first write something.";
    }
}
```

It's close to what I want to achieve, except the last stroke is not taken into account.
I guess that when the StrokeEnded event is triggered, the InkStroke has not yet been "processed" and thus it is not included in currentStrokes.

I tried to circumvent this problem by adding the Strokes corresponding to the InkStrokeInput of the event to the StrokeContainer I use as a parameter for the recognition :

```
InkStrokeContainer totalStrokes=new InkStrokeContainer();
if (currentStrokes.Count > 0) {
    totalStrokes= myInkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer;
}
totalStrokes.AddStrokes(input.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes());

var recognitionResults = await inkRecognizerContainer.RecognizeAsync(totalStrokes, InkRecognitionTarget.All);
```

But input.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes() returns an empty List.

Is there a way for me to access the current Stroke when the event is triggered ? Or is there another event I could use to call the handwriting recognition after the stroke has been "processed" ?
Or another way to automatically recognize the handwriting for all the current InkStrokes alltogether ?

Comment: Could you have an event that starts on `StrokeStarted` which just stores the number of strokes. Then when it comes to `StrokeEnded` have a while loop that waits on the count to be increased from the value stored from the initial event. I don't really know of `UWP` so I can't really provide code, but that's some logic that could work... you would have to be careful of the asynchronous behaviour however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a way to achieve the result I was expecting by calling my RecognizedAsync method when the InkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokesCollected event is triggered.

From the MSDN documentation :

> ### InkPresenter.StrokesCollected event
>
> Occurs when one or more ink strokes are processed ("wet" to "dry") by the >application thread.
>
> By default, an ink stroke is processed on a low-latency background thread and >rendered wet as it is drawn. When the stroke is completed (pen or finger >lifted, or mouse button released), the stroke is processed on the UI thread >and rendered dry to the InkCanvas layer (above the application content).